# How do I query an array of dictionaries in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have an array of dictionaries on which I have to make queries. The queries will be like when "name" is "a" then "value" should be "2".

```
{
    "t": "m",
    "y": "n",
    "A":[ 
            {
             "name": "x",
             "value": "1"
            },
            {
             "name": "y",
             "value": "2"
            },
            {
             "name": "z",
             "value": "1"
            }
        ]
}
```

In the above, I want to know what are the records whose "value" is "1" when "name" is x. 
I also need to make queries like, where "name" is "x" then value should be "2" and "name" is "y" then "value" should be "1"

Comment: Please post here, What have you tried so far?

Comment: db.collection.find({"name": "x", "value": "1"}) I have tried queries of this type. But I am not sure if it matches name and value from the same dictionary or not. Maybe it matches "name" as "x" from one dictionary and "value" as "1" from another "dictionary"

Comment: The thing to note that all dict will have a unique value of name. Suppose I want the records where "t" is "h" and the dict whose "name" is "x" it's "value" should be "2" and the dict whose "name" is "y" it's "value" should be "5"

Comment: Please see my answer hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 9):

You have to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to query embedded documents in an array if you want to query with multiple fields of embedded document. So your query should be like this:

```
db.collection.find( {
  "A": { $elemMatch: { name: "x", value: "1" } }
})
```

If you want query documents which have `(name:"x", value:"1")` **or** `(name:"y", value:"2")` in same query, you can use `$or`with elemMatch like this:

```
db.collection.find( {
  $or: [
    { "A": { $elemMatch: { name: "x", value: "1" } } },
    { "A": { $elemMatch: { name: "y", value: "2" } } }
  ]  
})
```

If you want query documents which have `(name:"x", value:"1")` **and** `(name:"y", value:"2")` in same query, you can use `$and`with elemMatch like this:

```
db.collection.find( {
  $and: [
    { "A": { $elemMatch: { name: "x", value: "1" } } },
    { "A": { $elemMatch: { name: "y", value: "2" } } }
  ]  
})
```

Comment: can a range query be done for querying array of dictionaries? Greater than equal to for example?

Comment: @cryanbhu You can combine $gte, $lte like operators with $elemMatch.

Answer (score 2):

I am using it like this and it's working.

```
db.collection.find(
                  {
                  $and:[
                       {"A.name":"x", "A.value": "2"},
                       {"A.name":"y", "A.value": "3"}, 
                       {"t": "m"}
                       ]
                  }
```

The above will give all records where "t" is "m" and where dictionary with name "x" has value "2" and dictionary with name "y" has value "3".

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to get the desired result
$unwind will unwind the array A, and then using $match we can pick out the matching documents.

Sample query

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
      {$unwind:"$A"}, 
      {$match:{"A.name":"x", "A.value":"1"}}
])
```

Sample result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59c9ee65f1287059437fa3ac"), "t" : "m", "y" : "n", 
   "A" : { "name" : "x", "value" : "1" } }
```

Comment: No need to aggregate for such a query requirement. Doing `$unwind` is overwork for this case.

Comment: @barbakini - Yes $elemMatch is best fit.