# embedded query in python3

Tags: python, mongodb

I am writing a program with python 3 and Mongodb
this is the structure of the collection I want to query:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef32b5ec3713c6fdc46fde6"),
    "by" : "mahsa",
    "contact" : [
        {
            "name" : "nazi",
            "family" : "joon",
            "phone" : "46578",
            "address" : "teh\n"
        }
    ]
}
```

and then in python 3 it is my first query :

```
myquery={'by':login.user}
mydoc=mycol.find(myquery)
print(list(mydoc))
```

and it is its result:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5ef32b4ec3713c6fdc46fde5'), 'by': 'mahsa', 'contact': [{'name': 'mahya', 'family': 'emami', 'phone': '56789', 'address': 'teh\n'}]}, {'_id': ObjectId('5ef32b5ec3713c6fdc46fde6'), 'by': 'mahsa', 'contact': [{'name': 'matin', 'family': 'mohamadi', 'phone': '46578', 'address': 'teh\n'}]}]
```

I want the code to get data from record with this fields:

name: Mahya
family: Emami

Comment: [$elemMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418832/how-do-i-query-an-array-of-dictionaries-in-mongodb), ```my_query = {"contact": {"$elemMatch": {"name": "nazi", "family": "emami"}}}```

Comment: tnx, but i mean how can i access to the value of  the name and family fields ?

Comment: i am writing a notebook and on this step i want say that show me contacts that is added by mahsa

Comment: That should be a simple for loop over the result set.

Comment: You need this, ```"\n".join([f"name : {c['name']}, family : {c['family']}" for x in list(mydoc) for c in x['contact']])```

Comment: sorry but i cant understand your mean :-(

Comment: now my result is list can i convert my result into dict instead of list ?

Comment: Can u add the expected output ?

Comment: myquery={'by':login.user}
        mydoc=list(mycol.find(myquery))
        print(mydoc)                                                                                                                   by this code my result is convert to list but i dont want it because it would easy if i  can access to the result by their keys b

Comment: but when i write it like this  myquery={'by':login.user}
        mydoc=mycol.find(myquery)
        print(mydoc)                                                                                                                     it dont show me the result  and show me this <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f35aa704e10>

Comment: so if i can convert my result to dict i think my problem would be solved . there is a way to do it ?